# How to change character set for ssh on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, ssh, character-encoding

I'm trying to connect to a server via SSH on Mac OS X however the username contains a pound sign "£" and and I am having some trouble using connecting. I can connect using other users but not if it has a "£" in the password.

In the past I have had this same problem and forcing the client (such as FileZilla which i do have working) to use the character set "ISO-8859-1" fixes the problem however I cant work out how or even if it is possible with the inbuilt ssh client on OS X.

Any ideas?

Comment: copy/paste it in

Answer (score 1):

Set the ISO-8859-1 encoding in `Terminal.app` settings, then launch `ssh` as

```
export LANG=en_US.ISO-8859-1
ssh [options]...
```

You can substitute `en_US` with your particular ISO language code, but it is not required to get the correct encoding.

Comment: Unfortunately that hasn't worked,  however I have discovered that JellyfiSHH (which if my understanding is correct is just simply a bookmark manager and just launches the terminal) works fine when I change the encoding which is puzzling. At least I can connect now.